# xfce4-terminal starts in ~/Desktop instead of ~

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, xfce, xfce4-terminal, documents

About a week ago (maybe after an update) the starting directory of xfce4-terminal changed from `~` to `~/Documents` when launched from the panel. I'm pretty sure that wasn't because of anything I have done: there are no `cd` commands in `~/.bashrc` (and that should not be necessary) and the launcher did not contain anything in the field 'Working Directory' (I put `$HOME` there just to try, but that does not work either).

```
$ grep cd ~/.bashrc
$ grep Desktop .config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc
$
```

I'm runnning Ubuntu 20.04, has anyone had this same thing happen in Ubuntu?

Comment: Does the same happen during SSH? Add the output of `getent passwd username` to the question.

Comment: Under *Edit → Preferences → General*, is `Working directory` set?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes I tried `$HOME` and `/home/<username>` but it seems to be overruled by something else?

Comment: @NasirRiley no, when I'm in my home directory and type `ssh localhost` I just end up in the home directory again. And, maybe stranger: If I am in my home directory and launch `xfce4-terminal` from there, it *also* starts in the home directory. I have removed the launcher and added a new one, with the terminal emulator, but it still starts in `~\Documents`.

Comment: What is the launcher pointing to?

Comment: @terdon the 'Command' field says `xfce4-terminal` -- is that what you mean?

Comment: Sounds like the `xfce-terminal` is configured to open in whatever directory it is launched from. What happens if you open a terminal, then run `cd /etc` and in there run `xfce-terminal`? Does it open a new terminal in `/etc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `xfce4-terminal` defaults to opening in whatever directory it was launched from. I just installed it on my Arch system, and confirmed the behavior. So I looked at its Preferences section (Edit => Preferences) and saw:

[image: screenshot of xfce4-terminal preferences]

So, just set that field to `/home/yourUser` and it should work.

It should, but at least on my system it does not! I tried this and the setting seems to be ignored which makes me think this is a bug in the program. You should let the developers know by filing a bug report, or you can wait until it is corrected.

In the meantime, as a workaround for your launcher, you can change the launcher so that it executes:

```
xfce4-terminal --default-working-directory=/home/yourUser
```

That should make new terminals open as expected.

Comment: Thanks -- will do! I did notice this as well, not sure if it was a bug or that there was some other directory setting that could still overrule everything.